# how to get response body during 400 error in http oubound gateway

Tags: response, gateway, outbound

i have

***gateway -> chain -> http:outbound-gateway -> transformer***

for the gateway i have error-channel to handle 400 responses from ***outbound-gateway.***

the payload I get in the error channel is the **MessageHandlingException**.
It does not have a way retrieve the response body.

Is there a way i can get response body as payload instead of exception.
Or is there a way if i can get hold of response body?

My 400 response has a body.

Comment: i feel in case of 400 (all error) responses the body of the response should be added as message of the MessageHandlingException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't spelled out in the docs, but it is available. The `MessageHandlingException` has a nested exception of `HttpClientErrorException`. That has captured the response body among other bits of useful information. To extract the response body, call `payload.getCause().getResponseBodyAsString()`